# Set '<location overrideMode="Allow"...' programmatically in applicationHost.config

Tags: iis, custom-action, appcmd

I need to allow the site I'm installing to override error page delegation so that it behaves correctly without affecting any other sites or settings on the web server.

First I tried editing the Xml with a C# custom action, but even though the custom action was running with full administrator privileges it couldn't find the file (FileNotFoundException). I've made various attempts with AppCmd.exe but I've not managed to change the applicationHost.config in any way that I can see, let alone the way I want (overrideMode="Allow"). I'm struggling to see why since this is so easy to change manually, it is so difficult in code.

The reason behind this attempt is I don't want a 500.19 HTTP Error if the root level feature delegation for error handling is set to say 'Read only'. In order words, I just want to install my application.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This the command I use to unlock the `system.webServer/security/ipsecurity` section:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd unlock config /section:system.webServer/secur
ity/ipsecurity
Unlocked section "system.webServer/security/ipSecurity" at configuration path "M
ACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST".
```

Note: this must be ran through an **elevated command prompt (Run as Administrator)**.

More info at [Getting Started with AppCmd.exe](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe).

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I will get a chance to try this out soon, I doubt it but I'll try.